# Wordpress: añadir como nuevo tema o modificar el actual?

Tags: php, wordpress, bootstrap-4, wordpress-theme, wordpress-widget

El año pasado cree mi primer sitio en `wordpress` con Bootstrap 4, completamente desde cero, por tal motivo mi página contiene varios errores y una maquetación digna de un novato que iba aprendiendo sobre la marcha.

Recientemente decidí crear un nuevo tema para mi página, otra vez desde cero, pero siendo consciente de las buenas prácticas y enfocado en ello. Ahora lo que quiero es subirlo a mi pagina de wordpress y darle esa apariencia, pero por falta de conocimiento en el campo me surgen algunas dudas sobre lo que realmente debería hacer:

1. ¿Debo crear un nuevo sitio en WordPress con el nuevo tema y luego
   conectar las bases de datos recuperadas del tema anterior?
2. ¿Debo subirlo como un tema adicional de mi página, activarlo y
   trabajar en base a ello?
3. De no ser así ¿Cual seria en todo caso el paso correcto para
   cambiarle la apariencia total a mi página?

En cualquier caso quiero evitar tener que modificar el tema viejo.

Con respecto al archivo `functions.php`:

1. ¿El tema nuevo deberá tener su propio archivo `functions.php` para
   registrar su `menú`, `área de widget`, etc?

Por ahora esas son mis dudas. De alguna manera intuyo en que debería subir el tema como un tema adicional de mi sitio (luego remover el tema viejo y colocar el nuevo por defecto), registrar los `menus`, `aside`, etc en `functions.php` y conectar en el nuevo tema mis campos personalizados, etc. Pero es lo que en mi ignorancia intuyo, no estoy para nada seguro de esto.

De antemano muchas gracias por su colaboración!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto es complicado, porque cada quien lo hace de forma diferente, aquí un ejemplo de como lo haría yo.

**1.** Haría una copia del sitio y la base de datos actual.
**2.** Crearía una instalación en local con la copia que hice anteriormente.
**3.** Los custom post types solo viven dentro del tema, por lo que al desactivarlo se perdería el custom post type, lo que haría seria convertir mis post type, metaboxes y demás data personalizada en un plugin, para que permanezca incluso si cambio el tema.
**4.** Con esa información rescatada, lo que haría seria comenzar a crear el nuevo tema desde cero, eso incluye el archivo funtions, index, page y demás archivos necesarios.
**5.** Una vez haya terminado con mi tema nuevo, haria una copia de mi instalación local y la pondría en la versión en línea, siempre guardando una copia por si es necesario.

También existen los temas en blanco, que pueden ser personalizados y generalmente ya vienen con algunas funciones, como integraciones con jetpack, puedes probar el tema https://underscores.me/

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. El paso 1 y 2 los hice previamente. Sobre el paso 3, asumiendo que mis CPT son los mas adecuados, estaría bien conservarlos. En mi caso por ser mis primeros CPT no son lo que precisamente me gustaría conservar para el nuevo tema. En ese caso me tocaría crearlos nuevamente pero de manera más inteligente. Me pondré a trabajar en el punto 4 y 5 y revisaré el dato extra de underscore. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, un saludo!!